# Index 1 beyond bounds when Populating table 2 with respect to table 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am looking to create a basic program for the ios that uses array of data and 2 UITableViews in one single view. I want the second UITableView to be populated by an array which is based on the selection made in first Table. I have an array of arrays for the second table. When I click on first cell of table1 then desired data is shown in table2. But when I click second cell of table1 I get error. "Index 1 beyond bounds"

.m file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/url.com/technology"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSString *jsonString1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/experience1"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSString *jsonString2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:url.com/experirnce2"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
SBJSON *parser1 = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
SBJSON *parser2 = [[SBJSON alloc]init];

NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
[parser release], parser = nil;
    NSDictionary *results1 = [parser1 objectWithString:jsonString1 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results2 = [parser2 objectWithString:jsonString2 error:nil];
    [parser release], parser = nil;
    [parser1 release], parser1 = nil;
    [parser2 release], parser2 = nil;

self.technologyArray = [results objectForKey:@"response"];
self.technologyData = [technologyArray valueForKey:@"technologyname"];
self.experienceArray1 = [results1 objectForKey:@"response"];
self.experienceData1 = [experienceArray1 valueForKey:@"experiencename"];
self.experienceArray2 = [results2 objectForKey:@"response"];
self.experienceData2 = [experienceArray2 valueForKey:@"experiencename"];
experience = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:experienceData1, experienceData2, nil];


}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == technologyTable)
return [technologyData count];

else {
return [experience count];
}

}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
// Change UITableViewCellStyle
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

    if (tableView == technologyTable)
{

   cell.textLabel.text=[technologyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

} 

if (tableView == experienceTable)
{
cell.textLabel.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[experienceTable reloadData];

}
return cell ;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == technologyTable)
{

experienceTable = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


selectTechnology.text = [technologyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

self.technologyList.hidden = YES;

}
if(tableView == experienceTable)
{
self.experienceList.hidden = YES;
selectExperience.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
[experience release ];

}
```

.h file

```
    {
NSMutableArray *technologyArray;
NSMutableArray *technologyData;
NSMutableArray *experienceArray1;
NSMutableArray *experienceArray2;
NSMutableArray *experienceData1;
NSMutableArray *experienceData2;

NSMutableArray *experience;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *technologyArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *technologyData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *experienceArray1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *experienceArray2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *experienceData1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *experienceData2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *experience;
```

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, when `(tableView == experienceTable)` why do you reload `experienceTable` ?

Comment: In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you are releasing `experience` array - make sure that is not causing this issue.

Comment: here experience is an array of 2 arrays. So when any selection is made in table 1. Table 2 gets populated accordingly. So had to reload table so that data can be updated according to the selection made. No releasing experience is not the cause.